# Proof rank(X)=k+1

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello I want to show that the $(k+1) \times (k+1)$ matrix
$$ X = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 &\cdots & 1\\
        1 & 2 & 2^2 &\cdots  & 2^k \\
        1 & 3 & 3^2 & \cdots & 3^k \\
        \vdots &&&\ddots \\
        1 & (k+1) & (k+1)^2 & \cdots &(k+1)^k \\ 
        \end{bmatrix}$$

(basically each row of this matrix has an integer $t=1,2,\dots ,k+1$ which runs from $t^0$ to $t^k$)

has rank $k+1$ . Any ideas or hints?

Comment: It's a Vandermonde matrix. Its determinant is a Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: Yep. Google Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: That's the same as $\ker X=0$. This can be shown straighforward by comparing $Xv$ to the [values of polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Applications) $v$.

Comment: They are called Superfactorials see https://oeis.org/A000178
rank is $k+1$ because determinant is never zero

Comment: Big thanks!! Got it.